# How is $() different from redirection?

Tags: linux, shell, terminal

Im learning the commandline from the book The Linux command line and I have a doubt.
Should not
`ls -l $(which cp)`
and `which cp | ls -l` have the same output?
Because I'm taking the output of which cp and passing it to ls `-l`
But that does not work as expected. `which cp | ls -l` instead displays the contents of `pwd`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`ls` doesn't care what's in the standard input.

```
echo anything | ls -l
                      ^^^
```

Since you haven't provided a directory to list, it will list the `pwd`.

Answer (score 1):

In the first case `ls` is receiving the result as an argument, in the second it is receiving it in the input stream (stdin), wich is ignored in this case.

You can convert from the input stream to arguments using [xargs](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/xargs.1.html) :

```
which cp | xargs ls -l
```